# Returned data using SUM does not appear correct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used the answers from here to answer my questions before, but I cannot find the answer to this question.

I am writing a query that needs to pull in how many drops a driver makes.  Fairly straight forward, however i need to add them together to give a total but when I use the SUM feature it does not return the correct information.

On the table Journey Header is a column with Number of drops, I need to add these up to give a total, which it does but i need my query to show the Driver, Vehicle, Total number of Drops and an Order Value, but I do not want each indivaidual record, I want them all grouped together, if that makes sense...

Below is the script i am using and part of the results beneath - for example I want the driver Chris Akwuba to show one line, with the total amount of drops he has done along with the order value (order value is working)

Thank you and I hope you can understand my rambling on....

```
select
sum(JH.NoofDrops) as [Number of Drops],
Jh.JourneyID,
JH.DriverName as [Driver],
VT.Name as [Vehicle Class],
SUM (OH.TotalSellPrice) as [Order Value]
from JourneyHeader JH with (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN VehicleType VT with (NOLOCK) on VT.VehicleTypeID=JH.VehicleTypeID
LEFT JOIN JourneyLine JL with (NOLOCK) on JL.JourneyID=JH.JourneyID
LEFT JOIN Orderheader OH with (NOLOCK) on OH.OrderID=JL.OrderID
where 
JourneyDate between '2012-06-01 00:00:00' and '2012-07-20 00:00:00'
Group by JH.DriverName, VT.Name, Jh.NoOfDrops, JH.JourneyID

Number of Drops JourneyID     Driver         Vehicle Class  Order Value
25          14520             Chris Akwuba       Transit            2533.32
1           14521             Kevin O'Sullivan   Hiab (Class2)  214.15
16          14522             Kevin O'Sullivan   Hiab (Class2)  1672.29
9           14523             Chris Akwuba       Transit            1136.69
16          14525             James O'Brien      7.5 tonne          633.18
9           14526             Errol Gray         Transit            768.17
25          14527             John Hardy         Transit            969.80
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Jh.NoOfDrops, JH.JourneyID` from the group by and `JourneyID` from the `select`
eg

```
Group by JH.DriverName, VT.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Even *if* you write the correct SQL, your results will be incorrect, always. Since you added the `with (NOLOCK)` hint, your are  asking to perform dirty reads you are getting back inconsistent data. See [Previously committed rows might be missed if NOLOCK hint is used](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx).

Now, if you're willing to ditch the 'gimme wrong results' hint, then you have a standing chance. But in order for that to happen, your requirements must not contradict themselves. When you say `I want the driver Chris Akwuba to show one line` you obviously cannot ask for the `JourneyID` column. You must make up your mind, either one row per Driver **or** one row per Journey. Not both. Once you settle one one of them, re-ask the question.